# Subspace Properties and Interior Points

Tags: general-topology

I am running into trouble finding a way through to part three of this question:

*Suppose $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$*:

a) Suppose **x** $\in$  $V$  and **x**+$\alpha y$ $\in$ $V$. First show $\alpha$y $\in$ $V$, then show if in addition, $\alpha \neq 0$, then $y \in V$

b) Suppose $x \in V$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Use part (a) to show if $r \gt 0$, and $B_r(x) \subset V$, then $y \in V$.

c) Use part (b) to show that if $V$ has an interior point, then $V = \mathbb{R}^n$

It is easy to validate part a, as we know that the subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

But how do we go about using this information in (a) to show that if there is an open ball such that $r \gt 0$, then $y \in V$

Moreover, how would we show that with (b) that $V = \mathbb{R}^n$?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $B_r(x)\subset V$, there exists $c>0$ such that $\|c(y-x)\|<r$, write $z=x+c(y-x)$, $z\in B_r(x)$ implies that $y-x\in V$ (part a), since $x\in V, y=x+y-x\in V$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! So if we are to use this to prove (c), are we to show that y is the interior point that we are looking for?